# selecting from table twice PHP SQL

Tags: mysql, join

i have a big problem and cant solve that:
i have a table (action) that store two id belong users in each row. one for customers and one for service providers.

[image]

name and family of these users are in another table (tablesite) that can be fetch. but i do not know how i can fetch either name and family of customers and also name of family of service_providers .

[image]

result should be like this:
example: first line `service_provider_id` is 33 and `customer_id` is 34
so i need this:

```
service_provider: sajad khammar --- customer: akbar ahmadi
```

Comment: Read the very basics about JOIN queries.

Comment: @hjpotter92 i know about join! i tried that but i only can fetch one name and family. either service_provider or customer because there is common column name and family for both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.job_id,
    CONCAT( s.name, ' ', s.family ) AS service_provider,
    CONCAT( c.name, ' ', c.family ) AS customer
FROM action a
INNER JOIN tablesite s
    ON a.service_provider = s.id_user
INNER JOIN tablesite c
    ON a.customer_id = c.id_user
```

Comment: can you please some explain?

Comment: @sajad I am just joining the same table twice, once for customer (`c`) and another for service provider (`s`).

Comment: @sajad The action table's alternate name (since typing `a` is easier than `action.job_id`)

Comment: i used this code in my main code but i have some problems. can you help me to fix them?

Comment: @sajad You should instead mention the problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94549/discussion-between-sajad-and-hjpotter92).